# How to use properly Postgres group by year, month in Django raw query?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

This is my first project when I'm using Postgres. Before I used sqlite3 and the syntax is different sometimes.

I have this query that works well in pgAdmin4:

```
SELECT auth_user.id, COUNT(coachregiszter_latogatoi_stat.id) AS count_id, DATE_TRUNC('year', datetime) AS year, DATE_TRUNC('month', datetime) AS month FROM auth_user LEFT JOIN coachregiszter_latogatoi_stat ON coachregiszter_latogatoi_stat.user_id = auth_user.id WHERE user_id=1 GROUP BY year, month, auth_user.id
```

If I implement it to my project I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

I know it points to this part `DATE_TRUNC('year', datetime) AS year, DATE_TRUNC('month', datetime) AS month` specially the '' marks at year and month but I can't find the solution what or how to use it in the project.

This is my code in Django:

```
ruser = request.user.id

coach_oldal_stat = Latogatoi_stat.objects.raw('SELECT auth_user.id, COUNT(coachregiszter_latogatoi_stat.id) AS count_id, DATE_TRUNC('year', datetime) AS year, DATE_TRUNC('month', datetime) AS month FROM auth_user LEFT JOIN coachregiszter_latogatoi_stat ON coachregiszter_latogatoi_stat.user_id = auth_user.id WHERE user_id=%s GROUP BY year, month, auth_user.id', [ruser])
```

Comment: You should paste in your Python code. Sounds like you may not be properly escaping your quote marks.

Comment: You are right, I forgot it. I added the Python code now. This is an escape problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, very simple.
I just had to change the single quotes to double `'SELECT ... '` to `"SELECT ... "`

Comment: Cool.  Don't forget the other way to deal with quotes within quotes within python is to "escape them" (put an escape character before them).  For instance:  `s = "this is \"a quote\" but it's ok"`.  And you can do the same with the other type of quote mark: `s = 'here\'s a string with an escaped apostrophe'`